# I can't insert xml file into sql swervber database table using copy data

Tags: azure

I have a solution that works but I hope to make it shorter. I'm only use pipeliane and not dataflow.
First I have a get metadata to get all files in a container.
Next I have a ForEachFile. This activity contains these two activity.

1. Copy file to arcive which is another container.
2. Copy to the same container naming the blob the same filename but with extension json.
   After the ForEachFile activity I have Delete all Xml files
   After this Delete all Xml files I have get metadata because now we have only json files in json format.
   Now we have a FoeachFile with one activity
   This activity is to copy the json with json format into sql server database table.
   The last activity is to delete all json files.

I have hoped to be able to use xml as the source and as sink be able to inser into sql server but this does not work. I have to first save to json before insert into sql server.
The xml file looks like this
[image]

The mapping I have done looks like this
[image]

I can't understand why I can't use xml as source and insert into sql server database table direct without saving to a new file before using sql server.

Many thanks in advanc

Answer (score 0):

You can directly copy xml data into SQL server without converting it into another file. Create linked services of blob storage and sql database create xml dataset with blob storage linked service and sql database dataset with sql database linked service. call copy activity and select xml dataset as source and sql server database dataset as sink and enable auto create table

[image]

Provide table in sql dataset with edit option.
Mapping:

[image]

Debug the pipeline it debugged successfully.

[image]

Selected data from table using `select  *  from dbo.input`

[image]

Pipeline JSON:

```
{
    "name": "CopyPipeline_3q5",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "xmlcopy",
                "type": "Copy",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [
                    {
                        "name": "Source",
                        "value": "files//input.xml"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Destination",
                        "value": "dbo.input"
                    }
                ],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "XmlSource",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
                            "recursive": true,
                            "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "XmlReadSettings",
                            "validationMode": "none"
                        }
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "AzureSqlSink",
                        "tableOption": "autoCreate"
                    },
                    "enableStaging": false,
                    "translator": {
                        "type": "TabularTranslator",
                        "mappings": [
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "path": "['id']"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "Id",
                                    "type": "Int16"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "path": "['direction']"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "Direction",
                                    "type": "Int16"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "path": "['count']"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "count",
                                    "type": "Int16"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "path": "['date']"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "Date",
                                    "type": "DateTime"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "collectionReference": "$['counts']['count']",
                        "mapComplexValuesToString": false
                    }
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "SourceDataset_3q5",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "DestinationDataset_3q5",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "annotations": [],
        "lastPublishTime": "2023-04-18T11:01:40Z"
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/pipelines"
}
```